# Is there a way to delete outdated code without manually cross-checking?

Tags: vba

I'm working on a VBA file which has become extremely congested with test sub-routines that I no longer need. I have three routines which Call a number of other routines, and everything that isn't called in these routines is of no use.

Is there any way of identifying these routines and deleting them, without manually cross-checking them against my Calls?

Comment: Rubberduck can check that: https://rubberduckvba.com (you will need to delete them yourself) • Otherwise you will need to check your code yourself.

Comment: Do you have all necessary and testing Subs in the same module?

Comment: I have about 12 modules.

Comment: Unfortunately Rubberduck does not work for me as that website is blocked from my work desktop. Great idea though.

Comment: Then happy checking I guess. There is no built-in tool in Excel to do that, and since third party tools are bocked for you the only chance I see is doing it manually.